# Java Thread in while-loop mystery

Tags: java, multithreading, loops, while-loop

I am developing a little jump and run game in Java. My game is overall based on an youtube tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1gir2R7G9ws).

I was creating a jump() method for the player. It works now thats cool but, I wanted that the player is moving 2 "fields" up with a velocity of 2.

So I created a while loop which is asking for the height (or y-value) every-time and if it is smaller or even, then it sets velocity to 0.

But for some reason I have to ask the Y value in the body of the while loop without doing anything with it in a extra thread (recognised that when it works while printing y).

```
public static void jump(GameObject pObject) {

                if (pObject.getSpeedY() == 0) {
                    int tmpY = pObject.getY();
                    pObject.setSpeedY(-2);

                    while (pObject.getY() >= tmpY - 64) {
                        new Thread(new Runnable() {         
                            public void run() {             
                               pObject.getY();              
                            }
                        }).start();
                        }
                    pObject.setSpeedY(0);
                }
}
```

I just wanna understand why I need that extra thread in the while loop because it just makes no sense to me. My assumption is because of some Java optimisation but I don't know. Thanks for teaching me!

This snippet also works.

```
public static void jump(GameObject pObject) {

                if (pObject.getSpeedY() == 0) {
                    int tmpY = pObject.getY();
                    pObject.setSpeedY(-2);

                    while (pObject.getY() >= tmpY - 64) {       
                              System.out.println(pObject.getY());               

                        }
                    pObject.setSpeedY(0);
                }
}
```

This snippet, however FAILS. While loop is infinite ergo it does not change the constantly changing y value!

```
public static void jump(GameObject pObject) {

                if (pObject.getSpeedY() == 0) {
                    int tmpY = pObject.getY();
                    pObject.setSpeedY(-2);

                    while (pObject.getY() >= tmpY - 64) {                   
                               pObject.getY();              
                        }
                    pObject.setSpeedY(0);
                }
}
```

Comment: You actually don't need it. Also, starting threads in a while loop like you do is a terrible idea. What are you trying to accomplish and what didn't work with your first approach?

Comment: the while-loop was infinite befor and never ended. Then I tried to print the y value in the while loop and then it works. I searched the println() method and saw that it is using somthing with threads so I tried this. I am no Java pro sry

Comment: in what way does `pObject.getY()` changes return value when repeatedly called? Is it being changed in different thread? If so, I think you should rethink your design.

Comment: I don't see tmpY being changed so that must be happening in a different thread. Perhaps the difference between the last code vs the two first is that performing an IO operation or creating a new thread may yield the current thread giving a different thread a chance to change the tmpY value, which is less inclined to happen in the last scenario which is all calculation.

Comment: This question isn't clear enough for me to figure out what's happening. Please post what happens vs what you expect to happen. Along with when and how pObject is created and manipulated. And whether it's happening in other threads etc.

Comment: @Snogg Edited it a little bit. Please answer the following questions.

1. What is the value of tempY?
2. What do you expect to achieve by this condition `pObject.getY() >= tmpY - 64`

Comment: Do yourself a favor and search for a different tutorial. Nothing more to say.

Answer (score 0):

The thread you are using there is pretty much useless.
All it does is get the y position of the player. 
Why even bother to get some information when you have no need for it.

Also, the thread is inside the while loop. This design causes huge negative performance impact. It is as if the code is creating 1000's of threads, all of which do nothing. CPU wastes the time in allocating and deleting the memory for the thread.

What you are trying to do is create a kind of lock. The CPU wont execute further statements until, some condition is fulfilled. If it doesn't your code is gonna get stuck.

This is especially tricky when using threads. In this case, your main thread will stop executing and possibly stop updating Y position of the player and you will go into an infinite loop.

We use a new thread only to check the player position. That way, main thread can update the position and new thread can listen to the player position. But, we will create only 1 thread, not 1000's of thread.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {         
    public void run() {
        while (pObject.getY() >= tmpY - 64) { continue; }
        pObject.setSpeedY(0)           
    }).start();
```